# Tomcat 7 is not running on browser(http://localhost:8080/ )

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Actually the apache-tomcat 7 server running at The Eclipse.but in browser getting error "The requested resource is not available." .Any reasons Please..?

Comment: check whether the server is already running in eclipse when you are trying to run it on browser if so, stop the eclipse server then try :)

Comment: Do you have any application mapped to ROOT? If not you will get this error.

Comment: what error are you getting anyway?

Comment: you didn't explain your problem clearly... you have eclipse-embeded tomcat? or standalone tomcat? which one was started? what did you mean "running at the Eclipse"? Is there any Exception, error message when you started your tomcat? did you check the log file? It is hard to give an answer/solution without knowing enough information.

Comment: Bhavik: Thanks for your response . using standalone eclipse only ,ya I have closed the Eclipse also . @Kent: Its working perfectly in Eclipse . But i need to retrieve from Browser at least welcome page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There could be a number of reasons, have it as a checklist and go through it

Is your server running on 8080?I mean that is the default port but it could be configured to run on other.

Also there is a possibility that the default application is removed/uninstalled that is why it is giving "the requested resource is not available"

Also it could be a proxy issue. make sure you are not using any proxy in your browser.

Comment: How do you do all these things

Answer (score 19):

When you start tomcat independently and type `http://localhost:8080/`, tomcat show its default page (tomcat has its default page at `TOMCAT_ROOT_DIRECTORY\webapps\ROOT\index.jsp`).

When you start tomcat from eclipse, eclipse doesn't have any default page for url `http://localhost:8080/` so it show error message. This doesn't mean that tomcat7 is not running.when you put your project specific url like `http://localhost:8080/PROJECT_NAME_YOU_HAVE_CREATE_USING_ECLIPSE` will display the default page of your web project.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue and for me, I tried changing the options in

- Server Locations

  and it worked.

  1. Double click on the Tomcat Server under the Servers tab in Eclipse
  2. Doing that opens a window in the editor with the top heading being Overview opens (there are 2 tabs-Overview and Modules).
  3. In that change the options under Server Locations, and give Ctrl+S (Save configurations)
     For me, **Use Tomcat installation (takes control of Tomcat installation)** worked
  4. Try starting the server and checking if localhost opens in the browser. Else select a different option.

I do not understand why that issue came up. I did search but did not find a relevant answer(Maybe I didn't use the right keywords). If someone knows **why that worked**, kindly share.

Thanks.

Comment: It worked because by default eclipse was deploying files on another location. now you explicitly mentioned server location and deploy path.

Answer (score 2):

1)Goto Server tab
2)Right on server -> general -> click on switch location.
3)Double click on the server -> under server location -> select tomcat installation.
4) restart the server.

Comment: please add this as comment, This is not answer

Answer (score 1):

It will be proxy configuration of your browser.
In NetWork Setting, use `no proxy`

For `Manual proxy configuration` add exception(No Proxy for in Firefox) like `localhost:8080, localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

You may face two errors while testing tomcat server startup.

1. **Error in the Eclipse inbuilt browser** - This page can’t be displayed
   Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to https://localhost:8080  again. If this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an unsupported protocol. Please contact the site administrator.
2. **404 error** in the normal browsers.

**Fixes -**

1. For the eclipse browser error, check whether you are using secured URL - https://localhost:8080. This should be http://localhost:8080
2. For the 404 error:
   Go to Tomcat server in the console. Do a right click, select properties. In the properties window, Click "Switch location" and then click OK. 
   Followed by that, Go to Tomcat server in the console, double click it, Under "server locations" select "Use Tomcat installation" radio button. Save it.

The reason for choosing this option is, When the default option is given as eclipse location, we will see 404 error as it changes Catalina parameters (sometimes). But if we change it to Tomcat location, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes another software can be holding this door and it can be the cause of this conflict, try change the door on the server.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the Tomcat Server under the Servers tab in Eclipse
Doing that opens a window in the editor with the top heading being Overview opens (there are 2 tabs-Overview and Modules).
In that change the options under Server Locations, and g

Answer (score 0):

You can run below commands.

```
 ./catalina.sh run
```

**Note**: Make sure the port 8080 is open. If not, kill the process that is using 8080 port using `sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)`

Answer (score -1):

Many of us get this error after setting up the eclipse and server for first time. This solution is -

> 1. go to **server tab**
> 2. select the **properties option** of your respective server and expand it
> 3. in the properties window , 
>          select **general** tab -> click **Switch Location** -> click **apply** 
>          ->click **ok**.

This may work .